# Manual acknolwedgement of sqs?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs

Currently we are using 'RabbitMQ' for reliable messaging delivery,we have plan to move SQS.RMQP monitors its consumers through TCP when any consumer of the Queue goes down it will automatically Re-Queue the messaging for processing.

Will SQS monitor all its slaves? Will the message is visible in the queue if one of its consumer goes down while processing the message?

I have tried to find out the same from documentation,i could not find any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by 'slaves', you mean SQS consumers, then no, SQS does not monitor the consumers from the queue.

In a nutshell, SQS works like this:

- A consumer requests a message from the queue.
- SQS sends the message to the consumer to process and makes that message temporarily invisible to other consumers.
- When the consumer is finished processing the message, it sends a 'DeleteMessage' requests back to SQS and SQS removes that item from the queue.
- If a consumer does not send the deletemessage back soon enough (within its configurable timeout period), then SQS will put the message back into the queue automatically.

So SQS doesn't monitor you consumers, but if a consumer requests messages - and does nothing with them - they will eventually end up back in the queue to be processed by someone else.

But if your queue doesn't have any consumers, then sooner or later (14 days max), the messages will be deleted altogether (or sent to a dead-letter-queue if you set that up).

It is usually a good idea to setup your queue consumers in an auto-scaling group, with a health-check that can verify that it is running/processing properly. If an instance fails a health check, it will be terminated and a new instance spun up to continue the work in the queue. Optionally, you can spin up extra instances if the size of the SQS queue grows to meet peak demand.